# Using Two Views with One UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am using one simple UIViewController for my application which is not too complicated.  It has two pages.  On the first page I enter data in to text boxes to indicate user changeable data which will be handled on the second page.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *routeText;
```

When I am running my actions on the second page, I use a command like this to access what was typed in to the text box:

```
NSString *variable = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",self.routeLabel.text];    
self.consoleView.text = variable;
```

But the value is always (null).  I am using the same TravelViewController.h/.m for all of the code.  My question is:  Is this not acceptable coding behavior to share it in this way or do I need to define the objects in a different way so the text can be shared between views?

Thanks for any help you could provide.

Comment: What do you mean by "second page"? How do you get to this page? Secondly, the initWithFormat method is unnecessary. You just write: self.consoleView.text = self.routeLabel.text;

Comment: Why is the `@property` you quote called `routeText` but the object you access called `routeLabel`?

Comment: @sjwarner. That was just an oversight. I have several of them with different names. They should match.

Comment: I have a view simple view with the text field on it and with buttons on it. The button is a modal connection to another view with the other actions that I hope to receive the text from the first page on.

Comment: I created the buttons and connections in the storyboard area, not by code. I created a single view app and copied the view and connected them.

Comment: I think what you copied was the view controller, not the view. Does the list on the left show 2 scenes that both say "View Controller Scene" at the top?

Comment: I think that you're right. How does affect how the app behaves? I'm assuming this is why they don't share information?

Comment: Yes, that's probably so. What you've done is create 2 different instances of the same view controller class. You really should use 2 different view controllers, and use the prepareForSegue: method to pass any value from the first to the second controller.

Comment: Can I create the second view controller scene and still put all the code in the same travelviewcontroller.m code or each view controller needs its own uiviewcontroller?  I'll check out the prepareforsegue

Comment: No, each controller needs its own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a different view controller you need to pass the text from parent view controller to child using @property. Declare it in second class and when you are pushing from first screen to second, set this value in @property. After that you can use it in second screen using self.text.